# how to display name from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, document.write

I have this part of my code and I am trying to have the user name display from firebase when a user comes to map. but when I run the code it erase all the html and prints 2 lines of code :

```
5Frederick619
•5Profile-10
```

essentially erasing all my code

```
<!--you can-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 youcan">
        <h4>You can:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><span>1</span> Track the location your friends my brother</li>
            <li><span>2</span> Track the location your friends my brother</li>
            <li><span>3</span> Track the location your friends my brother</li>
            <li><span>4</span> Track the location your friends my brother</li>
            <script>
                var endpoint;
                endpoint = new Firebase('https://keepitstreet.firebaseio.com/maps/openmap');
                endpoint.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
                    var uuid = childSnapshot.key()
                    var point = childSnapshot.val()
                    var username = childSnapshot.val();
                    var name = username.name;
                    document.write('<li><span>5</span>'+ name +'</li>');
                })
            </script>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/you can-->
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is meant to be used when opening a new window and inserting content into it, so when called on a loaded document, it will clear it. that's why your entire html is being deleted, except for the last thing your writing to the document.

what you need is to add the new item. you could do something like this:

```
function getPosts() {

  var endpoint;
  var list = document.querySelector('.youcan ul');
  endpoint = new Firebase('https://keepitstreet.firebaseio.com/maps/openmap');

  endpoint.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {

    var uuid = childSnapshot.key()
    var point = childSnapshot.val()
    var username = childSnapshot.val();
    var name = username.name;
    appendPosts(name)

  })

  function appendPosts(name) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = name;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }

}
```